# Java : can't decrypt what I encrypt

Tags: java, encryption, utf-8, cryptography, des

sorry if my question is silly but I'm learning java, I'm working on a project where encrypt and decrypt is needed I'm done with the code and the button for encrypting is fully functional but when I try to decrypt (different button) there is an error all the time.

encrypt code

```
 path = chooser.getSelectedFile();
             String x = path.toString();

             try {

                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(x));
                content = scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }

                try{

                    KeyGenerator keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
                    SecretKey myDesKey = keygenerator.generateKey();

                    Cipher desCipher;
                    desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");


                    byte[] text = content.getBytes("UTF8");


                    desCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);
                    byte[] textEncrypted = desCipher.doFinal(text);

                    String s = new String(textEncrypted);

                    try {

                         File statText = new File(x);
                         FileOutputStream is = new FileOutputStream(statText);

                         OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(is);  

                         Writer w = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                         w.write(s);
                         w.close();
                        } 
                 catch (IOException e3) {
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "something is wrong with the txt file");
                                    }                      
                }catch(Exception e1)
                {
                    System.out.println("En");
                }
```

and here is the decrypt part :

```
 path = chooser.getSelectedFile();
             String x = path.toString();

             try {

                 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(x));
                content = scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }

             try{
                    KeyGenerator keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
                    SecretKey myDesKey = keygenerator.generateKey();

                    Cipher desCipher;
                    desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");


                    byte[] text = content.getBytes("UTF8");
                    byte[] textEncrypted = desCipher.doFinal(text);


                    desCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);
                    byte[] textDecrypted = desCipher.doFinal(textEncrypted);

                    String s = new String(textDecrypted);
                    System.out.println(s);


                }catch(Exception e1)
                {
                    System.out.println("De"); /* here we go this is my error*/
                }
```

the error at the second code "catch(Exception e1)"

Comment: Well what error do you get?

Comment: You need to look at the exception object, it will tell you exactly whats wrong.  You should also not be using DES as its not considered secure.

Comment: You posted two code blocks, the first is encryption and the second is both encryption and decryption. Which part got the error?

Comment: @OcelotcR second code Exception e1 at the comment

Comment: "De" is not an error, it's a meaningless String. replace that System.out.println by e1.printStackTrace();

Comment: @Stultuske ok here what happened "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cipher not initialized"

Comment: so, check that code, see if that Getter is doing what it should

Comment: @Stultuske if you mean the scanner it's working 100% the only difference I find is the " desCipher " it has different value all the time

Comment: @abdulraman I was talking about the getter, not the scanner

Comment: @Stultuske oh the getter tor file path it's working I printed "x" and it was the correct  path

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems in your code. In your first part, you only sent the encrypted message and the receiver would not decrypt because you didn't send your key to the receiver. The second problem is you use `String s = new String(textEncrypted);`, you should send the `textEncrypted` instead of the string because converting bytes to string may lost some information due to encoding.

In your second part, you should call `desCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);` before encryption.

Comment: the key is fixed "DESKey@fffe78a6" the only thing that keeps change is "desCipher" it has a different value all the time

Comment: What error did you get? In the first part or the second part? If the error is initialized error, see my answer.

Comment: @abdulraman: that is *not* the key. That is a string describing the **reference** to the DESKey object, not the value of it.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I printed the key value and I was sly enough to believe it's the key but when I remove "UTF 8" and change some codes everything goes fine and I can encrypt the text 4 times and decrypt it 4 times and everything goes back the same.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved

encrypt code :

```
 path = chooser.getSelectedFile();
             String x = path.toString();

             try {
                 scanner = new Scanner(new File(x));
                content = scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
                try{
                    String desKey = "0123456789abcdef";   
                    byte[] keyBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(desKey);
                    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
                    SecretKey key = factory.generateSecret(new DESKeySpec(keyBytes));



                    desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");



                    byte[] text = content.getBytes();
                    desCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
                    byte[] textEncrypted = desCipher.doFinal(text);
                    String s = new String(textEncrypted);
                    try {
                         File statText = new File(x);
                         FileOutputStream is = new FileOutputStream(statText);
                         OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(is);    
                         Writer w = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                         w.write(s);
                         w.close();
                        } 
                 catch (IOException e3) {
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "something is wrong with the txt file");
                                    }


                }catch(Exception e1)
                {
                    System.out.println("relax and try again");
                }
```

Decrypt code:

```
 path = chooser.getSelectedFile();
             String x = path.toString();

             try {

                 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(x));
                content = scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z").next();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }

             try{
                 String desKey = "0123456789abcdef";   
                 byte[] keyBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(desKey);
                 SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
                 SecretKey key = factory.generateSecret(new DESKeySpec(keyBytes));


                    desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");


                    byte[] text = content.getBytes();




                    desCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);               
                    byte[] textEncrypted = desCipher.doFinal(text);
                    String s = new String(textEncrypted);



                    try {
                         File statText = new File(x);
                         FileOutputStream is = new FileOutputStream(statText);
                         OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(is);    
                         Writer w = new BufferedWriter(osw);
                         w.write(s);
                         w.close();
                        } 
                 catch (IOException e3) {
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "something is wrong with the txt file");
                                    }

                }catch(Exception e24)
                {
                    System.out.println("relax and try again");
                }
```

Thank you every one.